# How to merge a value to a Rails query as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a model named `User`, and I'm getting all Users with `User.all.as_json`.

The `User` model also has values of `first_name` and `last_name`, so my result would look something like this:

```
  [
    {
      "username"=>"johndoe",
      "first_name"=>"John",
      "last_name"=>"Doe"
    },
    {
      "username"=>"test",
      "first_name"=>"Test",
      "last_name"=>"Number 1"
    }
  ]
```

I want to add a custom value to each Hash in the array that looks like this:

```
  [
    {
      "username"=>"johndoe",
      "first_name"=>"John",
      "last_name"=>"Doe",
      "full_name"=>"John Doe"
    },
    {
      "username"=>"test",
      "first_name"=>"Test",
      "last_name"=>"Number 1",
      "full_name"=>"Test Number 1"
    }
  ]
```

`full_name` is not a model field, but instead a method of `get_full_name`. I don't know how to merge that key-value in each hash. This didn't work:

```
posts = Post.all.as_json.each do |post|
  post.merge({:full_name => post.get_full_name})
end
```

It returns the original result without the `full_name` value.

Comment: have you tried map instead of each in your example?

Comment: Don't try to merge to the JSON, merge to the hashes, then convert to JSON. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Note that SO isn't a discussion list. Grammar and spelling do count here, so "&" isn't a replacement for "and".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `Post.all.as_json` returns an array of hashes, with string keys. So you can't use the method get_full_name on the hash object.

You should convert your data to a hash inside your loop, and use a `map` instead of a `each` to keep your changes.

```
posts = Post.all.map do |post|
    post.as_json.merge({:full_name => post.get_full_name})
end
```

To get your `full_name` as a string key, you can use a string in your hash, instead of a symbol.

```
post.as_json.merge({"full_name" => post.get_full_name})
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider a serializer if this is not just a one-off thing:

The serializer would be a separate class that formats your data that way you want and would look something like (from railscasts by Ryan Bates):

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  def full_name
  end
end
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

Answer (score 1):

you can write as_json method in model and include method name as below

for example in you post model you can write like this

```
   def as_json(options = {})
    super(:only => [:username, :first_name, :last_name],
        :methods => [:full_name])
   end

   def full_name 
   "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

as_json supports :methods key, you can do it like this:

```
post.as_json( methods: :full_name )
```

also it might be delivered to the relations as well like:

```
 post.as_json( methods: [:full_name, :cool_name], include: { avatar: { methods: :url } } )
```